# Variable que nunca expira

Tags: php, mysql, variables

Tengo desarrollada una página en la cual se ingresará una única vez el nombre del usuario, nunca mas se regresará a esta página.

En la siguiente página se obtiene información entre ella el nombre que se ingresó en la primera página y luego se almacena en una base de datos.

He intentado con una variable de sesión pero en algún momento expira, también lo intenté con una variable de formulario pero si por alguna razón se pierde esa variable ya no obtengo el valor que necesito.

Uso `php` y la base de datos en `MySql`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var wait=setTimeout("document.geol.submit();",100000);
//-->
</script>
<input name="txtFirstName" type="hidden" id="txtFirstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtFirstName']; ?>">
```

Comment: Para este tipo de casos lo mejor es utilizar cookies

Comment: Sigo sin lograrlo, lo que necesito es que en una primer página se ingrese el nombre del usuario, este nunca deberá cambiar ya que nunca se regresará a esta primer página. Lo que he estado intentando es que en la segunda página esa variable en donde se capturo el nombre convertirla a texto simple y dejarla en un campo de un nuevo formulario. ¿Es esto posible?

Answer (score 1):

Pueba algo como esto para colocar un cookie

```
setcookie("Nombre_de_la_cookie","Valor(En tu caso el nombre del input)",Aquí le agregas el tiempo);
```